# Why doesn't my toggle work correctly when I use staticflies?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I am studying Django and found the following problem when using staticsfiles, the toggler that appears when the screen is reduced does not extend my bootstrap navbar, I did not find the error.

NOTE: the rest works, dropdown, navbar (css / js)

NOTE1: when I use CDN everything works, including the toggler

here are the excerpts that I call staticsfiles and the link to the complete project on github

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

**scripts.html**

```
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'jquery/dist/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

**navbar**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Los Angeles Soccer Evolution</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="programsDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Programs
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="programsDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lion Cubs</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Evolution</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lions</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Summer Camp</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="tournamentsDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Tournaments
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="tournamentsDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3 vs 3</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Futsal</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Schools</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
'''

[Projeto no Github][1]

[1]: https://github.com/ChenGit55/LASE
```

Comment: This is likely an issue with JS and HTML not Python. Please edit your question and include your navbar HTML.

Comment: are u sure? because when I use CDN everything works, but with the statics dont

Comment: Do you have errors in your dev tools console?

Comment: No, the server dont show any error

Comment: And your browser JS console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: collapse.js:346 to primitive value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused because on your server you are loading jQuery 3.5.0 or higher and via the CDN you were loading jQuery 3.4.1. See issue [#30553](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30553).

Try downloading jQuery 3.4.1 and using that. It looks like this will be fixed in Bootstrap 4.4.2